# Displaying several maps with leaflet in a table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, leaflet, thymeleaf

I am trying to display several maps within a table, using Leaflet & Thymeleaf. This means that I have to name each map container differently or otherwise I get an error because a container with such name is already initialised. I managed to do it using Thymeleaf's standard expression syntax and got no erros so far but the maps are not displaying. I am using these expressions to name the map container's id after a 'route id' which is a numeric string.
if anybody could offer some advice on what am I doing wrong, it will be much appreciated.

```
        <tbody>         
                <tr th:each="route: ${listRoutes}">
                    <form th:action="@{/delete_route}" method="get">             
                        <td><input type="hidden" name ="routeID" th:value="${route.id}" class="form-control"></input> [[${route.id}]] </td>
                        <td><div th:id="${route.id}"></div>Map Container </td>
                        <td th:text="${route.owner.id}">Owner</td>
                        <td th:text="${route.participants}">Participants</td>
                        <td style="cursor:pointer"><input type="submit" value="Delete Route" class="btn btn-primary" /> </td>                  
                    <script th:inline="javascript">          
                        var map = new L.map("[[${route.id}]]");
                        
                        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap </a>',
                        maxZoom: 18
                        }).addTo(map);
                            
                        L.control.scale().addTo(map);
                        var gpx = /*[[${route.directions}]]*/ "";
                        new L.GPX(gpx, {async: true}).on('loaded', function(e) {
                        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
                        
                        }).addTo(map);
                    </script>
                    </form> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: I am not able to recreate your problem - I can display maps in a table, similar to the code in your question. I _can_ recreate your problem if I do not set a CSS height and width for the map container. I set my height and width by adding a class to the map container `class="mapContainer"`, and then defining a style such as `.mapContainer { height: 200px; width: 500px;}`.

Comment: If that does not solve your problem, are you getting any specific errors in the browser console (F12 to open)?

Comment: Hi @andrewJames, thanks for the quick reply. Your solution seems to partially work for me.  I can now see the last map I load to the table but the ones before it are greyed out. I get a couple 404 errors as for some reason It cannot load the icons on the map, but this happens even with a single map.  So far I cannot see any specific errors.

Comment: OK - I see. All your maps are using the same variable `var map`. I can give you one approach to fix that, but it is a fairly significant change to what you currently have, given you are iterating with Thymeleaf: (1) Move all your map JavaScript into a single script, after the table; (2) Build an array of map objects `var maps = [];`. (3) Use Thymeleaf's support for [JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#javascript-inlining) to iterate over a list of your map IDs, and create each map by pushing it onto the array. Now you have separate map objects.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes to expand on my last comment in the question:

> (1) Move all your map JavaScript into a single script, after the table; (2) Build an array of map objects `var maps = [];`. (3) Use Thymeleaf's support for [JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#javascript-inlining) to iterate over a list of your map IDs, and create each map by pushing it onto the array.

I assume there is a `Route` class (or something similar), which looks like the following:

```java
public class Route {

    private final int id;
    private final int ownerId;
    private final String participants;
    private final String directions; // the URL of a GPX file

    public Route(int id, int ownerId, String participants, String directions) {
        this.id = id;
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
        this.participants = participants;
        this.directions = directions;
    }
    
    // getters not shown
    
}
```

The model then contains a `List<Route> listRoutes` for Thymeleaf to use.

The Thymeleaf template will look something like the following.

I have simplified this to remove the form, and to just focus on the overall structure & processing of the data:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="/js/my_script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css"/>

        <!-- leaflet and gpx -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
              integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
              crossorigin=""/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" crossorigin=""
                integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-gpx/1.7.0/gpx.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            .mapContainer {
                height: 200px;
                width: 500px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <table>
            <tbody>         
                <tr th:each="route: ${listRoutes}">
                    <td><div th:id="${route.id}" class="mapContainer"></div></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody> 
        </table>

        <script th:inline="javascript">
            var routes = /*[[${listRoutes}]]*/ [];
            //var maps = [];
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {

                routes.forEach((route) => {
                    let map = L.map(route.id.toString());

                    //maps.push(map);

                    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=YOUR TOKEN HERE', {
                        attribution: 'ATTRIBUTION INFO HERE',
                        maxZoom: 18,
                        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
                        tileSize: 512,
                        zoomOffset: -1
                    }).addTo(map);

                    L.control.scale().addTo(map);

                    var gpx = route.directions; // the URL of the GPX data
                    new L.GPX(gpx, {async: true}).on('loaded', function (e) {
                        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
                    }).addTo(map);
                });

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, the HTML table is much simpler.

The use of `<script th:inline="javascript">` allows Thymeleaf to render the `List<Route>` data as an array of JavaScript objects:

```
var routes = /*[[${listRoutes}]]*/ [];
```

After that, you can build each map as needed.

(I did not actually need to use `var maps = [];` - that part of my comment was incorrect.)

Comment: you are a star! It works! Thanks a lot!